# Filter the terms of a trigonometric SymPy expression, keeping those with a given coefficient

Tags: python, sympy

Let us suppose that we have an expression:

```
x*sin(y) + y*cos(x) + x*cos(z)
```

From the above expression, I want to obtain a new polynomial, having only the terms with the coefficient x, namely:

```
     x*sin(y) + x*cos(z)
```

or

```
  x*(sin(y) + cos(z))
```

Clearly, setting y=0 is not a solution, since x*sin(y) would become 0. How to filter the terms of a polynomial in SymPy to choose only terms with some give coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `collect`.

```
collect(x*sin(y) + x*cos(z) + y*cos(x), x, evaluate=False)
```

will return

```
{x: sin(y) + cos(z), 1: y*cos(x)}
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, this is not a trigonometric polynomial. Trigonometric polynomials have constant coefficients in front of cosines and sines.

With `expr.coeff(x)` you can get the terms that have `x` as a factor: that is `sin(y) + cos(z)`.

But if the expression was `x**3*sin(y) + y*cos(x) + x*cos(z)` then only `cos(z)` would be returned. Maybe this is what you want. But if the desired result for this example is `x**3*sin(y) + x*cos(z)`, then use

```
Add(*[v for v in expr.args if v.is_polynomial(x) and v.has(x)])
```

The logic is to filter the tuple of summands `expr.args` by the conditions that a term is a polynomial in `x`, and is a nonconstant polynomial. (Assuming you don't want to include constants).